# Validate Mandrill's X-Mandrill-Signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, mandrill

I'm developing a Node.js app and I'm struggling validating the Mandrill Webhook request.

As stated here http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23704122-Authenticating-webhook-requests it should be something like this in PHP:

```
/**
 * Generates a base64-encoded signature for a Mandrill webhook request.
 * @param string $webhook_key the webhook's authentication key
 * @param string $url the webhook url
 * @param array $params the request's POST parameters
 */
function generateSignature($webhook_key, $url, $params) {
    $signed_data = $url;
    ksort($params);
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $signed_data .= $key;
        $signed_data .= $value;
    }

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signed_data, $webhook_key, true));
}
```

So I came up with this:

```
var url = "http://....";
var post = "<POST Data>";
require('crypto').createHmac("SHA1", "<Webhook Signature Key>").update(url+post).digest("base64");
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I get a different signature.

The POST data comes urlencoded, e.g.:

```
mandrill_events=%5B%7B%22event%22%3A%22inbound ...
```

Urldecoded:

```
mandrill_events=[{"event":"inbound ...
```

The Mandrill doc says, that the delimiter should not be included, so this is the string I'm using (without `=`):

```
mandrill_events[{"event":"inbound ...
```

Any ideas about that?

PS: I double checked the URL and the Webhook Key :-).

Answer (score 3):

Use the URL (`config.url` in the example) and the key (`config.key`) that is displayed in https://mandrillapp.com/settings/webhooks for that specific Webhook.

In addition to the above response you have to make sure that forward slashes are escaped with a single backslash.

```
// mandrillEventsParamVal - how you get that depends on your request processor chain
var paramValEscaped = mandrillEventsParamVal.replace(/\//g, '\\\/');
var input = config.url + 'mandrill_events' + paramValEscaped;
var check = crypto.createHmac('sha1', config.key).update(input, 'utf8', 'binary').digest('base64');
```

The String called `check` is what you check against the header 'X-Mandrill-Signature'.

Comment: To be clear here, mandrillEventsParamVal should refer to the query portion of the URL, correct? Anything after the '?' in a url.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your input data format. You have to concat key/value pair, example:

var data = URL;
for(var key in POST_DATA)
   data += key+POST_DATA[key];

And now, you can check if base64(sha1(data, mkey)) is equal to the signature.